# Kimono Desktop Stopped Working?

Tags: kimono

Anyone having trouble building API's with the new Kimono Desktop app.  When I click create API the browser just stays on create API screen loading but nothing happens.

I even tried building an API that is the same as one I built when Kimono was still in business and no luck.

My existing api's still run and pull data fine.

Answer (score 0):

Working just fine here.
Just a shot in the blue...did you install the new extension specifically for the desktop app? The old one can't work anymore since Kimono disabled the online service.

Answer (score 0):

You can't build new APIs I think - only existing ones.  :( Said something like it was not the acquiring company's policy to provide this publiclu available service but since they did not know how many businesses depended on their APIs they decided to allow existing APis to run.

Comment: It is still very possible to create new scrape APIS with the Desktop app.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use their software for replace the online API. But it's an abandonware.
It's working great but on some website I can create new API because of an error.

I just find a possible (free) product that can replace Kimono : [Datascraping.co](http://datascraping.co).
They will include an REST FULL API within few days / weeks, as they said [here](http://www.datascraping.co/doc/questions/144/do-you-provide-an-api-to-start-crawling-read-results).

It's a good software, but comparing to Kimono Desktop it's a little much more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Kimono got bought out and it's not working anymore.
2. Import.io is good but it kinda expensive for me. I've tried the free trial before but see the price starts from $249, so...    https://www.import.io/standard-plans/
3. I don't have any progamming skills so I know very little about some web scraping frameworks like Scrapy.
4. You may want to look at this new web scraping software called Octoparse.
   In case you want to know, here is the link:http://www.octoparse.com/

It takes a little time to begin. But they have rich tutorials on the website. Plus it doesn't require programming skills. 
They provide cloud-based scraping service and API access. 
You  can use it to create API but you have to pay for the service. Free version doesn't have the API and cloud service.

I've been using it for 2 month with the [Standard plan $89](http://www.octoparse.com/pricing/), which a lot cheaper than import.io. So far so good.

Hope it would be helpful for you.